# Select item in custom dropdownlist in select function for kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendogrid I would like to select a different item than the selected one. This use case sounds strange, I know, but the idea is to pop up a window where you ask the user "Are you sure?" before assigning this new item.

If you click no, it assigns it to the original item. If you select yes, it sets the new item.

Here is the basic setup:

```
$('<input id="uniqueIDYo">')
.appendTo(container)
.kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: true,
    dataTextField: 'Name',
    dataValueField: 'Id',
    filter: 'contains',
    template: `blahblahblah`,
    dataSource: {
        data: data.models
    },
    select: function(evt) {
        if (/* ask user question here = yes */) {
            // cool, set the value
        } else {
            // THE QUESTION: How do I set the selected value back?
        }
```

Here's the problem with the question, I have no idea how to set the value from in here. The only partial solution I've found is to immediately drop an evt.preventDefault() at the top of the select function. This is not ideal as I do want the value to change if the user answers yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

here is the dojo for it:
https://dojo.telerik.com/OqORUJES

and the code

```
<select id="my-select"></select>
<script>
    let people = [{
            id: 1,
            fullname: 'David Lebee'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            fullname: 'Chuck Norris'
        },
    ];

    function confirmAsync(success, fail) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (confirm('are you sure')) {
                success();
            } else {
                fail();
            }
        });
    }

    $('#my-select').kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: 'fullname',
        dataValueField: 'id',
        dataSource: {
            data: people
        },
        select: function(e) {
            let selectedItem = e.dataItem;
            let widgetInstance = e.sender;
            let id = e.dataItem.get(widgetInstance.options.dataValueField);
            e.preventDefault();
            confirmAsync(function() {
                widgetInstance.value(id);
            }, function() {
                // nothing to do because of prevent default. 
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I had no idea I could get the sender via the event object!

Comment: My pleasure, glad i could help.